# Update "Last seen" as the user requests something

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

I have noticed that users do some activity somewhere and their last seen is not updated according to it. For example, they comment on a question *a minute ago* but their last seen will be like ~*15 mins ago*.

Can the last seen be updated as the user:

- Requested his achievements *(clicked on the recent achievements)*
- Requested for inbox *(clicked on the recent inbox messages)*
- Opened any question
- Clicked on the list of Stack Exchange sites *(Button on the top right corner)*
- Requested the new questions *(clicked on* X new questions with new activity *)*
- Commented somewhere
- Answered somewhere

<sub>- Etc</sub>

Though this list won't be complete, it looks bad that the user did that activity right now but the profile says he was last seen a long time ago.

Comment: Probably someone that doesn't think this is a good plan. Thats how meta works.

Comment: Not my downvote, but I don't think it's particularly useful (see my answer for why) and [voting is different on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta): *On posts tagged feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself.*

Comment: Most users prefer to ***remove*** the "last seen", or at least make it less accurate, since it makes SE act more like social forum and harm privacy. See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285220/reduce-precision-of-last-seen-to-hours-rather-than-minutes) for example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding the purpose of the 'Last seen' indicator. Stack Exchange is all about the *content*, not the *users*, and the indicator is just a simple tracker which you can use to give you a rough idea if you can expect a response from that user. I'm sure you only have positive intentions but it isn't meant to [stalk users to the minute](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/320870/4751173).

I'm also pretty sure that some of the actions (e.g. posting a comment/answer) already update the 'Last seen' indicator, but the time displayed on the profile is [invalid due to caching](https://shouldiblamecaching.com). Other things, like reading the achievement dialog or inbox, are stored at the *network* level and can never update the 'Last seen' indicator which is on *site* level.

- Glorfindel *(last seen 2 hours ago)*

Comment: Some pretty slow caching going on here